# crontab does not execute aws s3 cp commands

Tags: bash, shell, cron, sh, aws-cli

I have a shell script file which reads

```
#!/bin/bash 

s3_up_bucket=<my bucket name>
s3_access_key=<my access key>
s3_secret_key=<my secret key>
curdate=2018-04-06

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$s3_access_key AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$s3_secret_key aws s3 cp officemaster-2018-04-06.tsv.gz s3://$s3_up_bucket
```

When i manually execute this script, it works fine.

But when I execute this script from crontab, the file is not getting uploaded to AWS s3.

0 9 * * * /absolute-path-to-file/file.sh

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: the command `aws` is in the crontab's PATH?

Comment: in your crontab, you have to give the account with which the script run? example: `0 9 * * * <user> /absolute-path-to-file/file.sh`

Answer (score 0):

You must be in your working dir as your file path is relative

```
#!/bin/bash 

s3_up_bucket=<my bucket name>
s3_access_key=<my access key>
s3_secret_key=<my secret key>
curdate=2018-04-06

cd /myworkdir/

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$s3_access_key AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$s3_secret_key aws s3 cp officemaster-2018-04-06.tsv.gz s3://$s3_up_bucket
```

Comment: You can check the output of your cron (root email or syslog)